# Telnet in Windows didn't connect

Tags: windows, telnet, cmd.exe

I want to connect to my friend's computer using telnet, but when I type: telnet [his IP], it didn't work. It also happens when he types my IP. The command line said that he can't connect on port 23.

What should I do?

Comment: Over lan? Wan? Firewalls on? off? Router in between?

Comment: Is a telnet server running on the remote machine?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be sure that **telnet server** is running. This is the concept of client-server on network. Say if a web server is not running on host www.microsoft.com you can type as many times as you like http://www.microsoft.com in your browser but an error message will appear in your browser saying that either host is not found or not responding. This is what is likely to be happening to you with telnet. The other bit - a software **firewall** on windows may be blocking telnet traffic (port 23), so you might need to enable it via Windows firewall (or other firewall that you may have).

In Windows telnet server is controlled via **Telnet service**. Go to `Services` via `Control Panel - Administrative Tools` and enable the service there. You will have options to run it immediately and to schedule to be run automatically at startup.

Having said that you should know also that telnet is run in plaintext so all your telnet exchange, including password, can be monitored on the wire through tools like Wireshark. In *nix systems SSH is by far the default protocol used for what telnet was used about 20 years ago. It still makes great tool for exploring networking.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm form windows setting weather your telnet feature is on.
path=win+turn on windows features on/off + on telnet client+ on telnet server+on TFTP client.